# Jupyter Notebook malfunctioning

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter

I am running Julia and Python on Jupyter notebook. I like the UI and the auto indentation and other features (I'm a beginner). However, while running Julia today the entire notebook just appears blank. The code blocks are not colour coded, and there is no auto indentation. However, when I open a Python notebook/change the kernel from Julia to Python, it works as usual. **I have attached pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giy4V.jpg) for comparison.**

I don't know what has changed. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Adding some code for reference:

Julia

```
using Plots

function lattice(N)
    lat = zeros(N,N)
    for i in (1:N)
        for j in (1:N)
            if rand() < 0.5
                lat[i,j] = 1
            else lat[i,j] = -1
            end
        end
    end
    return(lat)
end
```

Python

```
import numpy as np


def ran_ini_cond(L):
    spins = np.zeros((L,L))
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            spins[i,j] = np.random.choice([1,-1])
    
    print('inital lattice')
    return(spins)
```

These are two different versions of the same program I am trying to run on Julia and Python. The code works, but a lot of the IJulia and/or Jupyter notebook features are disabled for Julia (as seen in the pictures).

Comment: Can you please add a picture showing this behavior? Are you sure you are typing in a code cell and not a markdown cell?

Comment: @logankilpatrick I have added a picture in the link mentioned in the post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.